# c++ only first answer line correct

Tags: c++

I get problem with my program ,it prints correct only first line answer here is my .txt file,first number (3) is shops number,second number (5) is products number ,other lines is prices for products

```
3 5
1.27 2.92 3.45 1.09 0.89
1.08 2.25 3.75 1.12 0.69
0.98 2.48 3.62 1.10 0.72
```

And here`s my results.txt file ,in witch are all results of each line

```
 9.62
 8.89
 8.90
```

My program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double dienos, results;
    int shops;

    ifstream fin ("duomenys1.txt");
    fin >> shops;

    for( int shop = 1; shop <= 3; shop++ ) {
        results = 0;
        fin >> dienos;

        for ( int pricelist = 1; pricelist <= 5; pricelist++ ) {
            double price;
            fin >> price;
            results += price;

        }
        cout << results << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What is it supposed to do? 2. How is it incorrect?

Comment: it is supposed to calculate each line summary ,first line summary is correct ,  9.62 ,other lines is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that in:

```
ifstream fin ("duomenys1.txt");
    fin >> shops;

    for( int shop = 1; shop <= 3; shop++ ) {
        results = 0;
        fin >> dienos;
```

The `fin >> dienos` should be outside of your loop.

Also both loops are hard-coded, rather than using the values read.

Comment: thanks,it helped.Also can you said how i can calculate all three answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double dienos, results;
    int shops;

    ifstream fin("duomenys1.txt");
    fin >> shops;
    fin >> dienos;

    for (int shop = 1; shop <= shops; shop++)
    {
        results = 0;
        for (int pricelist = 1; pricelist <= dienos; pricelist++)
        {
            double price;
            fin >> price;
            results += price;
        }
        cout << results << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works,also can you tell me how to calculate all ,three , answers,thanks